# How do I filter a view based on a multilingual alias?

Tags: i18n-l10n, views

I have a view with a contextual filter which builds a page based on a product's model number. The path is /support/%, where % is the contextual filter for the model number.
This works fine for English content. I would like additionally take a path of /assistance/% for French content. How can I have one view with two, or variable paths?

Answer (score 1):

You can not two views with same path.
You need to create copy of the view and change its path.

For french language you need to use filters? When you create your view, you add a new filter and select "Node translation" from the "Groupes" list and the check "Node translation: Language" and click "Add". Then you can chose language(s) on which you want the view to show.

Comment: Ok, I figured you might need two views. Then the issue is the language toggle won't redirect you to the other language's view. Is there a hook to alter the path of the language toggle links?